# Debugging a failing Android Gradle Build - transformClassesWithMultidexlistForDebug FAILED

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, android-gradle-plugin, android-multidex

I am having this terrible problem. I am not all that well versed in Android builds at all beyond the basics. And i am building from inside Unity.

My build for android fails with a "transformClassesWithMultidexlistForDebug" (or Release variant) error.

> com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException: Error while generating the main dex list.

I highly subject some classes are colliding. But i can not for the life of me convince this build process to spit out any more info on what is actually causing that action to fail.

--debug and --info result in little useful info, or i can not find it in the walls and walls of text that produces.

So my question is, how do i go about resolving my build issues? 
How do i find what is the matter in this process?

I would like some info to go on instead of the only approach i have right now, which would be to randomly take out/add library files until it *maybe* resolves the build issues?

Thanks in advance for any help you can give me!

Comment: Probably related:https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52032516/error-building-apk-com-android-build-api-transform-transformexception-error-w

Comment: I can find at least 15 more related posts. Variants have no more info to go on than i do. And suggestions range from conflicting classes, wrong versions of Gradle, to outright memory limitations. I tried all of them that i could find. None solved the issue so far.

Comment: Btw taking out files from the `Library` won't change anything since it is rebuild by Unity. Do you have any PlugIns in use?

Comment: Plugins like what? Ironsource is the only android thing i am trying to add. And it has a build in resolved for google play services and such. that is all i know about plugins.